# Find $\mathbb P(\frac{1}{4}<x<1)$ from the CDF given

Tags: probability-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions

Cumulative distribution function of a random variable is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb F_X(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 &  x<0 \\ 
x^2 & 0\leq x<\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \leq x<1 \\
1 &  x\geq 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

Find $\mathbb P(\frac{1}{4}<x<1)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments. If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\mathbb P(\frac{1}{4}<x<1)=F_X\left(1^{-}\right)-F_X(\frac{1}{4})$